# Android OpenGL Error (not using OpenGL in my app)

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm getting crash reports from one of my apps, from a user with a Nexus 4 running 4.3. From what I understand, this error is caused by OpenGL. I don't use OpenGL in my app. Can anyone give me a hand with this?

Here's the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not create an EGL context. eglCreateContext failed with error: EGL_SUCCESS
    at  
android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.createContext(HardwareRenderer.java:1192)
    at 
android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initializeEgl(HardwareRenderer.java:1044)
    at
android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initialize(HardwareRenderer.java:979)
    at
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1536)
    at
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
    at
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
    at
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
    at
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
    at
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
    at
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
    at
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
    at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
    at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
    at
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you sure it's Android 4.3? Android 4.4 just start getting deployed to the Nexus 4 yesterday. What does your app do anyway?

Comment: See if you can replicate the error on a remote Nexus 4 here: http://developer.lge.com/resource/mobile/RetrieveVirtualLab.dev

Comment: Positive that it's 4.4 (I have built in logging that reports the version (among other info) at the time of a crash or developer report. The log right before this crash is in a method that uses `MediaPlayer`. This takes place in a `Service`. However, right after the `Service` is started an `Activity` is also started. I don't see any of my breadcrumb logs from the `Activity` so I'm guessing it's not the cause. I'll look into that link. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry that was a typo. I'm positive that it's 4.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is an Android (or perhaps Google Play Services) issue, and not specific to your app.  There are a couple of other tickets/threads open that discuss this issue:

- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61868
- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/nexus/qkzrUEA-UbM/WqZiK6AjXzwJ
- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2513412

I have encountered this on my Nexus 4, and am hoping Google provides a fix soon.

Comment: Here's one more link that I could not post due to a lack of reputation points:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2513412

Comment: Thanks for the other links. I've been following the issue on the Android issue page, and I'll have a look at the others.

Answer (score 6):

Just happened to me on my Nexus 4.
it seems to cause about half my apps to crash, looks like it's a glitch in the matrix.

Rebooting the phone solved it.

Comment: Same here. Pretty much all apps crash. How bad.

Comment: What do you mean by a glitch in the matrix?

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=glitch%20in%20the%20matrix (def 2)

Comment: This is becoming a major issue for me really. I completely factory reset my nexus 4 and the issue came back. I am running 4.3 on a Nexus 4 and the device has little but the core os and apps. In my own app, I cannot see how I would be using Open GL...

Comment: If you have "developer options" in settings, disable anything related to GPU, specifically "Force GPU rendering" might be causing this, but some other might be related as well